# What did the Yuuzhan Vong use for doors?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, yuuzhan-vong

Wookieepedia has again turned up empty. I know it's some kind of membrane thing that acts by expanding and contracting a hole. Does anyone know what it's called?

Comment: whatever it is, I hope it doesn't hit them on the way out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you looking for "[hatch sphincter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hatch_sphincter)"?  It's a semi-independent biot used to create a seal in another structure, IIRC.  Quoting from *New Jedi Order: The Unifying Force*:

> The five of them hurried down the angled ramp and through the slowly sealing breach the concussion missiles had blown in the thick **hatch sphincter.** The hideously torn membrane opened onto a vast, dimly lit cavern of yorik coral.
>
> <sub>*New Jedi Order: The Unifying Force*, Chapter 37</sub>

But not all doors are independent biots; lots of building-type organisms have their own internal membranes that can act like doors, but which are part of the building itself.  For example, quoting the description of a [damutek](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Damutek):

> Intruders that entered the giant plant had to contend with **membranes that closed their pathways** as well as a poisonous gas that was emitted by the structure-sized organism. Certain individuals, however, managed to gain entry by calling out the password when touching **the door organisms.**

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: That's starting to sound correct. I'm not completely convinced so I'll give it 24 more  hours or so before accepting. I think hatch sphincter is what I'm looking for; whatever was used on the inside of the capital and world ships. I am a little worried that only 2 books were listed in the appearances section, so I may be looking for something else.